# how to map json data (not by for loop)?

Tags: json, react-native

Here is my Json data:

```
data = {
   "what would you like to have?": {
      "susi":0,
      "rice":0,
      "noodles":0,
      "manchurian":0
   },
   "what you will have in breakfast?": {
      "Idli":0,
      "dosa":0
   }
}
componentDidMount() {
let newPost;
      var id='-M6YIRfep3uFjaEv4fzL';
      const db=   firebase.database();
      const events =db.ref().child('PG');
      var query= events.orderByKey().equalTo(id);
      query.once("value",(snapshot)=>{
           newPost=snapshot.val();  
           const keys = Object.keys(newPost);
           for (let data of keys) {
             const keys = Object.keys(newPost[data].poll);
               console.warn(newPost[data].poll);
               for(let k1 of keys)
               {
                  //console.warn(k1);
                  const keys2 = Object.keys(newPost[data].poll[k1]);
                  this.setState({
                    data1:newPost[data].poll[k1]
                     })
}
}
 render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: 410,
              height: 600,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              alignContent: 'center',
            }}>
  {
                  this.state.data1.map((item,keys)=>(
                    // item[keys].map((items,key)=>{

                      <Text>{item[keys]}</Text>

                   //})
                 ))
                }
  </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I map this data as I am iterating through for loop it is working but as I am doing with map function it is showing an error of
undefined is not an object (evaluating `object.keys(this.state.data )`) in react native .
 iam getting the data1 variable as i warned the data1 its waring the data1 .But not rendering the data

Comment: Can you show us your function where you iterate over your data?

Comment: I suspect it's cause you're trying to `.map` straight away and not waiting for the `this.state.data` to be filled. Just try to do `this.state.data && Object.keys(this.state.data).map...`

Comment: the data iam getting it in componentDidMount () and iam displaying or maping my data it in render function ,return function . i have edited my code take a look